# Jasypt Encryption Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/encryption/StringEncryptor

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jasypt

I have simple java console application, where I have used Jasypt1.9.2 for encryption purpose of the database connection string. The code runs perfectly fine in Eclipse,but application exported as Jar give this error[image]

This is my simple Main class:

```
    public static void main (String args[])
 {
try {


            GetConnection config = new GetConnection();
            out = config.getLogFile();
            System.out.println("Start");
            Interface.writeLine(out, "Start");

            while (true) {
            new Interface().ProcessProcedure();
            new Interface().ProcessKTP();
            new Interface().TransferToPRF();
            System.out.println("End");



        Thread.sleep(90000);
            }



        }
        catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error:"+ex);
        }
    }
```

And this my GetConnection class

```
public Connection getSql(BufferedWriter out){

        try{


                StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();       

                prop = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);    //--fOR ENCRYPTED PASSWORD


                String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\configuration.properties";
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);    



            //InputStream inputStream;



                if (is != null) {
                    prop.load(is);
                } else {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Configuration property not found");
                }


            String Driver =  prop.getProperty("sqlserver.driver");
            String url = prop.getProperty("sqlserver.durl");
            String id = prop.getProperty("sqlserver.uid");
            key = "123"                                                      
            encryptor.setPassword(key);                                     
            String sqlpass = prop.getProperty("sqlserver.pass").trim();


            Class.forName(Driver).newInstance();
            Connection conMSSQL = DriverManager.getConnection (url,id,sqlpass);




            if(conMSSQL != null && conMSSQL.isValid(0)) {

                GetConnection.writeLine(out,"Connection established");


            }
            return conMSSQL;
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){

                GetConnection.writeLine(out,"Exception at Kondor connection");  
                GetConnection.writeLine(out,ex.getMessage());


                return null;
            }


    }
```

I have check and verified the classpath for the Jasypt1.9.2.jar entry.
Please help in this.

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the JVM tried to access a class but didn't find it.

You've exported your project to a JAR file without exporting the dependencies with it.

Select the `package` or `repack` option while exporting it from eclipse.

This adds the dependencies to the exported JAR file.